# How can I fully reallocate a 2D array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, multidimensional-array, realloc

Being concise, I want to read a file and store the content in a 2D array, where the first dimension refers to the line and the second dimension to the character in the respective line. I do not know the number of lines and columns on each line beforehand.

The code I tried is as follows.

P.S.: I know the variables's names are not that good XD

```
FILE *filepointer = fopen(commandlineargument.filtersfile, "r");
int numboflines = 0;
int numbofchars = 0;
char **array = malloc(numboflines + 1);
array[0] = malloc(numbofchars + 1);
char currentchar; 
while(fscanf(filepointer, "%c", &currentchar) != EOF)
{
    if(currentchar != '\n')
    {
        array[numboflines][numbofchars] = currentchar;
        numbofchars++;
        array[numboflines] = realloc(array[numboflines], numbofchars + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        array[numboflines][numbofchars] = '\0';
        numbofchars = 0;
        numboflines++;
        array = realloc(array,  numboflines + 1);
    }
}
array[numboflines] = '\0';
numboflines--;
```

With the code above, I can just get the value of `array[0][0]` and only before it gets reallocated two lines down (then `array[0][0]` points to null). I get Segmentation Fault later.

P.S.: I know the code above will only work properly if the last line ends with a `\n`

An example of the desired output:

File Content:

```
>Abcde
fghijk
>Lmno
pq
```

2D Array values:

```
array[0][0] = ">"
array[2][1] = "L"
```

And so on.

Comment: Just to be clear, you aren't talking about a 2D array, which would have type `char [A][B]` or, as a pointer, `char (*)[B]`. Rather, you're talking about a jagged array, i.e. an array of *pointers* to arrays.  It's often used for the same thing, but is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, but it has one omission and one mistake:

**The mistake:** memory space for each element of array is not a character, but a pointer to a character, so this line:

```
char **array = malloc(numboflines + 1);
```

should be rewritten as this:

```
char **array = malloc((numboflines + 1)*(sizeof *array));
```

**The omission:** after you end a line and realloc array, you must malloc the newly array element:

```
numboflines++;
array = realloc(array,  numboflines + 1);
```

Becomes:

```
numboflines++;
array = realloc(array,  (numboflines + 1)*(sizeof *array));
array[numboflines] = malloc(numbofchars + 1);
```

Comment: Oh. You are totally right. I' m not on the computer right now, but will test as soon as possible and accept your reply here.